# any? for a has_many association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `User` model which `has_many` `groups`.

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    has_many :groups, MyApp.Group
[...]
```

In the `user#show` template I'd like to render the existing `groups` if there are any. If there are none I'd like to render nothing.

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```html
[...]
<%= if @user.groups do %>
  <h2>Groups</h2>
  <ul>
  <%= for group <- @user.groups do %>
    <li><%= group.name %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
[...]
```

But that doesn't work. In Rails I'd use a `@user.groups.any?`. How can I do this in Phoenix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the groups collection isn't an empty list or use the `Enum.empty?/1` function:

```
if @user.groups != [] do
  # ...
end

if not Enum.empty?(@user.groups) do
  # ...
end
```